# How to add text inside QGraphicsPolygonItem while using QPolygonF for drawing?

Tags: python, pyqt

I was wondering how do you add text inside `QGraphicsPolygonItem` ?
In my script , I use `QPolygonF` and `setPolygon` for drawing items and I was wondering if you can insert text inside it ?

I was doing some research, but all I could find is that some people use `QGraphicsTextItem` instead of polygon item or using `QPainter` which I don't know how to combine with my `QPolygonF`. Can somebody advice me how to solve my problem ?

Edit:

Sorry for not providing any example. Here is example of polygon item -

```
from PySide2.QtGui import QColor, QPolygonF, QPen, QBrush
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QPointF, QPoint
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsPolygonItem, QApplication, \
    QFrame, QSizePolicy

points_list = [[60.1, 19.6, 0.0], [60.1, 6.5, 0.0], [60.1, -6.5, 0.0], [60.1, -19.6, 0.0], [60.1, -19.6, 0.0],
               [20.0, -19.6, 0.0], [-20, -19.6, 0.0], [-60.1, -19.6, 0.0], [-60.1, -19.6, 0.0], [-60.1, -6.5, 0.0],
               [-60.1, 6.5, 0.0], [-60.1, 19.6, 0.0], [-60.1, 19.6, 0.0], [-20.0, 19.6, 0.0], [20.0, 19.6, 0.0],
               [60.1, 19.6, 0.0]]


class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.create()

    def create(self, **kwargs):
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        graphics = MainGraphicsWidget()
        main_layout.addWidget(graphics)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)


class MainGraphicsWidget(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainGraphicsWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self._scene = QGraphicsScene(backgroundBrush=Qt.gray)
        self.setScene(self._scene)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor(30, 30, 30)))
        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding))

        self.testButton = GraphicsButton()
        self._scene.addItem(self.testButton)


class GraphicsButton(QGraphicsPolygonItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.myPolygon = QPolygonF([QPointF(v1, v2) for v1, v2, v3 in points_list])
        self.setPen(QPen(QColor(0, 0, 0), 0, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.FlatCap, Qt.MiterJoin))
        self.setPolygon(self.myPolygon)
        self.setBrush(QColor(220, 40, 30))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setGeometry(500, 100, 500, 900)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So here should be red square like item in center and does anybody know how to put some text inside ?

Here is screenshot of shapes and text which I would like to get:
[image: Shapes and text]

Comment: What do you call "inside" the polygon? You could put several examples with different polygons.

Comment: Thanks for noting it. I added some example of how I use QGraphicsPolygonItem.

Comment: I think you did not understand my question, let's say you have a polygon as one of the ones that show the following image: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQknVpLiY9qi7Zwtepu2DkhIHUlxcend6HiegBlp3D9eL6slpNc&s, Where should the text be ?, You realize that there may be more "complicated" polygons, for example let's say there are 2 squares joined by a very thin and long rectangle.

Comment: Ohh... I see what you mean. Nothing complicated , it's more of like simple squares, circles, ellipses. Most complicated shape would be something like hand shape - https://st4.depositphotos.com/18664664/21429/v/1600/depositphotos_214299026-stock-illustration-hand-icon-vector-isolated-on.jpg and text would be somewhere always in center - in readable place. Nothing like 2 separed shapes or zig zag

Comment: You must clearly define what you call "simple" in this case, in addition to how you define inside or better how the central position of that "inside" is calculated.

Comment: One possible definition is to calculate the center of the minimum area rectangle that covers the region (polygon) whose sides are parallel to the edges of the screen, do you agree?

Comment: Probably you are right, I thought about that , but have no clue how to do that calculation and how to insert text with those calculations. (I edited my question and added screen shot of exact shapes I will use and painted how i see my text there)

Comment: I think that my criteria are not suitable for the body since the text would be located a little higher, mmm, I think that what you require is more part of computational geometry than with the GUI which is what Qt focuses on.

Comment: I see, but how would you put text if it were rectangle? Like the one I provided in script above. How do you put text there ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is to add a [QGraphicsSimpleTextItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicstextitem.html) that is a *children* of the graphics item.
For simple shapes as rectangles and [regular polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon) you can then place the item at the center of the item. Remember that the text will not consider the parent item shape, and you'll have to take care of it in some way; this means that you have to consider the text *width* and *height*, and parent item shape (that's true for irregular shapes, but also for triangles and rotated squares).

```
class GraphicsButton(QGraphicsPolygonItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # ...
        self.textItem = QGraphicsSimpleTextItem('I am a very large rectangle', self)
        rect = self.textItem.boundingRect()
        rect.moveCenter(self.boundingRect().center())
        self.textItem.setPos(rect.topLeft())
```

As you can see, the result is outside the parent boundaries:

[image: text outside the parent item]

A possible alternative is to use the [QGraphicsTextItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicstextitem.html) and set its [textWidth](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicstextitem.html#setTextWidth):

```
        self.textItem = QGraphicsTextItem(self)
        self.textItem.setHtml('<center>I am a very large rectangle</center>')
        self.textItem.setTextWidth(self.boundingRect().width())
        rect = self.textItem.boundingRect()
        rect.moveCenter(self.boundingRect().center())
        self.textItem.setPos(rect.topLeft())
```

[image: text inside the parent item]

Note that, opposite to the QGraphicsSimpleTextItem (which uses the default black color for painting), QGraphicsTextItem uses the current palette WindowText [role](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum) of the widget, inherited from the application, from the view, or from any of the view's parent that has *previously* set it (once the default text color is set, it won't be changed even if the palette has changed).